# Не работает кнопка delete в React

Tags: const

```
const handleDeleteItem =(id) =>{
 setItems(prev=>prev.filter(item=>item.id!==id))

<ul className="list-group todo-list">
        {filteredItems.map((item) => (
          <li
            key={item.key}
            className="list-group-item"
            onClick={() => handleItemDone(item.key)}
          >
            <span className={`todo-list-item ${item.isDone ? "done" : ""}`}>
              <span className="todo-list-item-label">{item.label}</span>

              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm float-right"
              >
                <i className="fa fa-exclamation" />
              </button>

              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right " onClick={()=>handleDeleteItem(item.id)}
                key={item.id}
              >
```

Comment: как именно не работает?

Comment: не удаляет то что хочу. Например, нажимаю удалить "Happy Hacking" а он не удаляется